# After decoding using ijkplayer why decoded frames have no Y, U, V frame data although being YUVJ420P

Tags: decoding, ijkplayer

In ijkplayer, after decoding, the obtained frame has no YUV planes data[0], data[1], data[2] are all null and similarly linesize[i], although pix_fmt is YUVJ420P. Can anyone please tell me why?